# primary school operations with Latex

Tags: math-mode

I want to do in LateX a sheet of activities for primary school like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific in your question? And like ... actually ask a question?

Comment: Please add a minimal example showing what you tried yourself so far. This is not a „Do this and that for me. I’d don’t like to spend time on it my self“-community.

Comment: There is no reason to continue downvoting this question. Rather we should _explain_ why this question could be improved.

Comment: Now I try to explain what could be improved: We have no idea where your specific question is: do you want to know how to put things on a grid? How to include graphics?  How to arrange the calculations? You could help us giving better answers by providing more detail where you are stuck.

Answer (score 10):

I answer me,
the package [`xlop`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/xlop) is the solution.

An exemple is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xlop}
\begin{document}
\opadd[carryadd=false]{1234}{3456}
\end{document}
```

[image]