# Is it possible to write algorithms in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to present a vertical multiplication/addition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11702/how-to-present-a-vertical-multiplication-addition)

Like, for example:

```
  9
+ 8
---
 17
```

Is this possible? Is there a specific LaTeX thingy (like `\frac`), or is custom markup needed?

Comment: Will this previous question help you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11702/how-to-present-a-vertical-multiplication

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Primary school operations with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56963/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you might have found your answer in the comments, here how you could use the [xlop package](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/generic/xlop/xlop-doc.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document}
\opadd{9}{8}
\end{document}
```

Which will result in:

[image: Output]